# How do you update existing VMSS?

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I'm lost as far as how do I work with existing deployment of VMSS which I perfomed using template in powershell. For example I want all VMs to have additional extension installed now and this was not part of original template. How do I add this extensions to all machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply deploy the template again. It will only deploy the difference (so make sure you use the same username/password etc!)

minor edit: if you have upgradePolicy.mode set to "Manual", you will also have to do a "Update-AzureRmVmssInstance" call on each VM you want updated; if it's "Automatic", it will go out to all VMs automatically in parallel; if it's "Rolling" (preview here: https://github.com/Azure/vm-scale-sets/tree/master/preview/upgrade), it rolls out in batches.

Comment: I'm surprised ARM is smart enough to deploy only changes.

Comment: It is desired state after all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Add-AzureRmVmssExtension PowerShell cmdlet to add an extension. Install the latest version of Azure PowerShell if you have not already.
Or 'az vmss extension set' if using CLI, for example in the Azure Cloud Shell.